# Behaviour of the solution of a non-local ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am studying the following non-local ODE in $f$
$$\dot f(x) \left\{\log(x + \varepsilon) - 2\log(f(x))\right\} + \int_{x}^{2x_0} \frac{\dot f(s)}{s + \varepsilon}ds = c$$
for some constant $c \in \mathbb R$. This ODE is defined on the interval $[0, 2x_0]$, where $x_0$ is an arbitrarily small positive number (meaning that we can take as small as we want), and $0<\varepsilon \ll x_0.$
Solving directly such an equation is clearly not doable. Moreover, it seems natural to take the derivative in order to get rid of this non-local term. This leads to the second order ODE

\begin{align}
0 &= \ddot f(x) \left\{\log(x + \varepsilon) - \log(f(x))\right\} - \frac{2(\dot f(x))^2}{f(x)}  \\
&= \ddot f(x)f(x)\left\{\log(x + \varepsilon) - \log(f(x))\right\}  - 2(\dot f(x))^2
\end{align}

Solving this equation directly seems a bit delicate to be tackled directly. However, I would be interested to study the behaviour of the solution of this equation. More precisely there a solution (or an approximate solution) such that $$0 < \varepsilon < \dot f(x) \le \frac{1}{|\log(x + \varepsilon)|^2}$$
for every $x$ ? Any help or guidance would be welcome.

Comment: If it's non-local it's not an ODE.

Comment: Well, any ODE can be transformed into an integral equation... It seems that this one becomes a second-order ODE rather easily. I believe that if you negate $x$, you can write the first-order equation as a delay-differential equation with distributed delay, for which there is a lot of literature, but I imagine that the second-order system may be easier to analyze.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you for your comment. Could you precise what you mean by negate $x$ ?

Comment: Let $t = -x$, then the domain of integration is $t<0$, corresponding to a delayed state.